# uninitialized constant Controller::Yt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am trying to use the YT gem to retrieve channel information from YouTube but I keep on getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ChannelsController::Yt
```

I am using Devise and Omniauth Google and when the user logs in, I am saving their access token to the database as part of my from_omniauth method as such:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.access_key = auth['credentials']['token']
    end
  end
```

Then trying to pass this to YT::Account.new as such:

```
def edit    
    # get youtube account    
    @account = Yt::Account.new access_token: current_user.access_token
    email = @account.email
end
```

YT is install in my gem file as such:

```
gem 'yt', '~> 0.25.5'
```

I am at a bit of a loss of what is going on, any thoughts?

Many thanks
David

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after that?

Comment: @Pavan - yes i have but still no joy